# Ordenação de HashMap por valor e atribuir a uma dto usando java 8

Tags: java, java-8, collection

Atualmente tenho o seguinte cenário **funcional**:

Uma lista da classe Studios com id e nome: `List<Studios> studios;`

Faço a contagem dos nomes repetidos no `List` dessa forma:

```
Map<String, Integer> counts = new HashMap<>();
studios.forEach(studio -> counts.merge(studio.getName(), 1, Integer::sum));
```

No `Map<String, Integer> counts` tenho como `key` o nome e como valor o total de repetição encontrado no `List studios`: `Key = "Xpto", value = 5`.

Ordeno o retorno do `Map counts` desta forma:

```
result = counts.entrySet().stream()
    .sorted(Collections.reverseOrder(Map.Entry.comparingByValue()))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, 
        (e1, e2) -> e2, LinkedHashMap::new));
```

Obtendo como resulta o json:

```
{
    "Studio1": 6,
    "Studio3": 5,
    "Studio2": 4
}
```

Minha necessidade é passar uma dto no momento da ordenação para obter o retorno do json da seguinte forma:

```
{
  "studios": [
    {
        "name": "Studio 1",
        "cout": 6
    },
    {
        "name": "Studio 2",
        "count": 5
    }
  ]
}
```

Minha Dto:

```
public class Dto {
    private String studioName;
    private Integer count;
}
```

Obs: Aberto a sugestões de como melhorar o código serão bem-vindas.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tente utilizar o método **map** da Stream e crie um construtor ou algo pra inicializar a classe Dto, como apresentado abaixo:

```
Map<String, Integer> counts = new HashMap<>();
studios.forEach(studio -> counts.merge(studio, 1, Integer::sum));

List<Dto> lista = counts.entrySet().stream()
        .sorted(Collections.reverseOrder(Map.Entry.comparingByValue()))
        .map(item -> new Dto(item.getKey(), item.getValue()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());


public class Dto {
    public Dto(String studioName, Integer count) {
        this.studioName = studioName;
        this.count = count;
    }

    private String studioName;
    private Integer count;

}
```

Comment: Acertou na veia +1.